# Na classe especializada devo utilizar self ou parent para acessar as variáveis?

Tags: php

Tenho duas classe, uma abstrata (**Conector**) e uma classe especializada (**ConectorWmi**) que estende de *Conector*.

Minha dúvida é, considerando o código abaixo, na classe especializada devo ao invés de chamar **self::$conexao**, chamar **parent::$conexao** e **parent::$mensagemErro?

Classe abstrata:

```
abstract class Conector
{
    /**
     * Recurso de conexão externa
     * 
     * @var object
     */
    protected static $conexao;

    /**
     * Mensagem de erro
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected static $mensagemErro;

    /**
     * Realiza conexão com o host alvo
     * 
     * @param   string  $host
     * @param   string  $usuario
     * @param   string  $senha
     * @param   int     $porta
     * @param   int     $timeout
     * @return  void
     */
    abstract public static function conectar($host, $usuario = null, $senha = null, $porta = 135, $timeout = 10);

    /**
     * Consulta o status da conexão
     * 
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function status()
    {
        return (self::$conexao !== NULL) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna mensagem de erro gerada durante a tentativa de conexão 
     * ou erro gerado na chamada do método "executar"
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public static function mensagemErro()
    {
        return self::$mensagemErro;
    }

    /**
     * Executa a instrução remotamente
     * 
     * @param   string $instrucao
     * @return  object
     */
    abstract public static function executar($instrucao);
}
```

Classe principal:

```
class ConectorWmi extends Conector
{    
    /**
     * Estabelece conexão com máquinas Windows via chamada COM
     * 
     * @param   string  $host
     * @param   string  $usuario
     * @param   string  $senha
     * @param   int     $porta
     * @param   int     $timeout
     * @return  void
     */
    public static function conectar($host, $usuario = null, $senha = null, $porta = 135, $timeout = 10)
    {
        try
        {
            /**
             * Testa conectividade com host alvo
             * 
             * @param string $host
             * @param string $porta
             * @param int    $errno   valor de sistema
             * @param string $errstr  mensagem de sistema
             * @param int    $timeout tempo máximo a esperar
             */    
            if (!$socket = @fsockopen($host, $porta, $errno, $errstr, $timeout))
            {
                // @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
                $dic = [
                            10056 => "Já existe uma conexão socket aberta para o host <b>{$host}</b>!",
                            10057 => "Não foi possível conectar ao socket na chamada do host <b>{$host}</b>!",
                            10060 => "Time Out na chamada do host <b>{$host}</b>!",
                            10061 => "O host <b>{$host}</b> recusou a conexão!",
                        ];

                $mensagem = (array_key_exists($errno, $dic)) ? strtr($errno, $dic) : $errstr;          

                throw new RuntimeException("Erro ({$errno}): {$mensagem}");
            }

            fclose($socket); // Fecha o socket aberto anteriormente

            $WbemLocator = new COM("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
            // @see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393720(v=vs.85).aspx
            self::$conexao = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\cimv2', $usuario, $senha, 'MS_416');
            self::$conexao->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;
        }
        catch (com_exception $e) {
            self::$mensagemErro = utf8_encode($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e) {
            self::$mensagemErro = $e->getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            self::$mensagemErro =  $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executa a instrução remotamente
     * 
     * @param   string $instrucao
     * @return  object
     */
    public static function executar($instrucao)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!self::$conexao)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Erro: É necessário abrir uma conexão antes de tentar executar qualquer comando!");
            }
             // @see http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php
            return self::$conexao->ExecQuery($instrucao);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

E na classe especializada, seria importante ou recomendado dá um return no método status e mensagemErro?

```
public static function status()
{
    return parent::status();
}

public static function mensagemErro()
{
    return parent::mensagemErro();
}
```

Comment: o parent vc normalmente usa quando precisar "subir" para a implementação de quem vc herdou (no caso de estar reimplementando). Por exemplo, seu "limparRegistros()" faz alguma coisa especifica, mas chama o parent:limparRegistros() para completar o procedimento com o que a implementação base já faria. Em condições normais é sempre self.

Comment: Um à parte @Bacco e Fábio, e para dar razão ao Bacco. Se a classe mãe não fosse abstrata seria sempre `$this->` , que é o equivalente ao `self`, se não existir reimplementação na classe filha o metodo da classe mãe é que é chamado

Comment: Mudei essa estratégia estática para: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166611/qual-a-melhor-abordagem-para-lidar-com-código-fracamente-acoplado

Answer (score 3):

Por alguns testes que fiz é relevante usar `parent::` se na classe abstrata e na que a extende houver um metodo com o mesmo nome e quiser chamar o metodo da classe mãe (abstrata), ex:

```
<?php
abstract class hey {
    protected function hello() {
        echo 'hello from hey';
    }
}
class lol extends hey {
    protected function hello() {
        echo 'hello from lol';
    }
    public function do_hello() {
        self::hello();
        parent::hello();
    }
}
$lol = new lol();
$lol->do_hello();
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/rQihh0)

Mas caso não haja (tiver mesmo a certeza que não há um método com o mesmo nome), pode restringir-se ao `self::` que este vai à procura do metodo na classe onde é chamado e se não encontrar vai à procura na classe *parent* (abstrata), ex:

```
<?php
abstract class hey {
    protected function hello() {
        echo 'hello from hey';
    }
}
class lol extends hey {
    protected function adeus() {
        echo 'hello from lol';
    }
    public function do_hello() {
        self::hello();
        parent::hello();
    }
}
$lol = new lol();
$lol->do_hello();
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/d1SMP8)

como pode ver ambos executaram o metodo da classe abstrata `hey`, e não o da `lol`, porque `lol` não tem nenhum metodo `hello()`.

MAS, no caso de PHP, por uma questão de legibilidade e se a sua intenção for chamar o metodo/variável da classe mãe mesmo que a/o tenha reimplentado na filha eu faria `parent::$conexao`

Contudo acho desnessário criar metodos para aceder a essas variáveis da classe mãe, pudendo só `parent::$status` e `parent::$mensagemErro` onde for necessário.

Comment: Compreendi. Em termos de boas práticas, seria ainda recomendado chamar na classe que estendeu Conectar os métodos mensagemErro e status? Só para deixar visível (conforme questionei na pergunta), ou isso não seria aconselhável?